# Accessing properties from a function in Web Components

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x

I am converting a project from Angular to Web Components / Custom Elements and am trying to replace `ng-model` by creating a binding for the following text field:

```
<input type="search" class="form-control search_input" placeholder="Search for someone new" value$="[[userLookup:input]]" required autocomplete="off">
```

Obviously since this is converted from Angular, I need to be able to access this value in a JavaScript function:

```
(function(customElements) {
    class RecentSearch extends PolymerMixins.LightDomMixin(Polymer.Element) {
        static get is() { return 'recent-search'; }

        static get properties() {
            return {
                properties: {
                    user: {
                        type: Object
                    },
                    userLookup: {
                        type: String,
                        reflectToAttribute: true,
                        value: '',
                    },
                },
            };
        }

        lookupUser() {
            if (this.userlookup) {
                $state.go('users', { query: userlookup });
            }
        };
    }
    customElements.define(RecentSearch.is, RecentSearch);
})(window.customElements);
```

How would I access the `userLookup` property (the one bound to the text field) from inside the `lookupUser` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already accessing `userLookup` **correctly** from `lookupUser()` with `this.userLookup`. The event handler's context (i.e., `this`) is the Polymer element instance.

However, your data binding is incorrectly a one-way data binding, so `userLookup` would not be updated. This kind of [binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#two-way-native) needs to be two-way (i.e., with curly brackets) and **cannot** use attribute binding (i.e., `$=`).

The correct usage should be something like this:

```
<input placeholder="Search for someone new"
       value="{{userLookup::change}}" />
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/aWxbxz?editors=1011)